# Why read garbage inode while creating a file is OS?

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems

I am studying operating systems from the book OSTEP. In the file-systems implementation chapter, there is a file creation timeline, which displays what operations are done on what type of file-system elements(inodes, data blocks, inode/data bitmaps etc) when you create a file. Following image displays the timeline.

[File Creation Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xObGl.png)

Suppose we want to create a file `bar` in `/foo/`, so the file will be `/foo/bar`. what data elements will be accessed?
I understood following steps

(1) Start reading from `root`, to go to location where we want to create a file, so first we read the inode of root so that we can access its data block to find what is the inode number of `foo` directory.
(2) Read from root data block the inode number of `foo`.
(3) Now read from inode of `foo` to find location of its data block.
(4) In the data block of `foo`, we check whether there is any file with name `bar`. We can only proceed with creation if there is not, because Linux does not allow same filenames in same directory.  
(5) Assuming we can proceed, we read from inode bitmap to find which inode is available for allocation. 
(6) Then we allocate that inode by writing to corresponding bitmap location of the above discovered inode. 
(7) Then we make an entry in `foo` for the file of `bar`. The entry will be a pair `('bar', <inode no of bar>)`. So a write in `foo`.
(8) Now I'm stuck from this read done in the inode of `bar`. Why do we need to read from this inode?

I think we should write straight away in the inode of bar. We have to write metadata of bar to this inode right? Then why de we read hear?